# overflow-x inside 1fr grid item not working

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In a `display: grid` container, I have 2 child div's.
I want the sizes of the div's be like:

1st div: 300px
2nd div: *Take remaining width*

For Div 2, I want a horizontal scrollbar if the table doesn't fit inside the div.
This works as long as I define an exact width value but breaks when I use `1fr`.

**Snippet (HTML)**

```html
<div class="wrapper p-4">
  <div class="first">
    Some info
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Hello</td>
              <td>There</td>
              ...
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Hello</td>
              <td>There</td>
              ...
            </tr>
          </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet (CSS)**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;

.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
...
```

[image: Example]

Code: https://codepen.io/studiojw/pen/ExEXyYZ

Comment: Please post [mcve] not an external link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.second` element is overflowing. That is the issue. Add `overflow-x: scroll` to the `.second` element and that will do the task.

Also you will have to remove the `overflow-x: auto;` given to `.table-wrapper` to avoid double scrollbars

Answer (score 1):

Adding min-width property to immediate children of grid should fix the problem. [This overflow happens because a grid is a layout system based on a content minimum size (as the float layout)](https://datacadamia.com/web/css/grid/overflow). You can set min-width to 0.

```
.wrapper > * {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is really working for fractional cells

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

`grid-template-columns: 300px auto;`

This should make the 2nd div take the available space